# Why is Visual Studio no longer letting me open a simple flat website folder?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I've always used VS2010 to open a bunch of flat websites which live on my local disk (File -> Open -> Web site).

e.g Foobar website at:

```
c:\Projects\Foobar
```

This traditionally worked fine (whether or not VS2010 is the right tool for editing simple HTML files)

However, I've moved to a new PC and this simple idea of opening a flat website inside VS2010 is all screwed up.

It'll open any folder once but if I try and reopen the website it has thereafter decided that I want my website *content* in a subfolder. It spawns a subfolder at

```
c:\Projects\Foobar\Foobar
```

and is *determined* to use that for content (of course it's empty, and no, I don't want to adopt that folder structure).

Is there any way to force VS to use my plain old root folder website as it used to on my old machine?

**Edit**
I can, sort of, get to what I wanted by deleting both the `foobar.sln` file and the `foobar/foobar` folder and then reopening. But as soon as I then exit and try to reload the website VS complains:
`Unable to open the Web site 'C:\Projects\foobar\foobar`

Answer (score 0):

The `foobar.sln` file is just a simple XML file with a path to every relevant project.  Open the site in VS once, then close it and edit the `.sln` file manually (in Notepad or something similar).  Look for the folder path `C:\Projects\foobar\foobar` and change it just `C:\Projects\foobar`.